# Magento Cart and Checkout pages giving error 500

Tags: magento, php

**Hello,**

I have some weird issue with our Magento store:

We're getting 500 error (blank page) on our /index.php/checkout/cart/ and  index.php/checkout/onepage/

By taking a look @ error log, we get the following:

```
ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /home/headsh78/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/eon/template/catalog/product/featured.phtml on line 90 and defined  in /home/headsh78/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
```

and

```
ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::init() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, null given, called in /home/***/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/eon/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml on line 82 and defined  in /home/***/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php on line 139
```

The corresponding code is as follows:

```
  <?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
      foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
      //echo var_export($image); ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(71, 65); ?>" width="71" height="65" alt=""/>
  <?php }  ?>
```

and

```
public function init(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeName, $imageFile=null)
```

Is anyone willing to help us out?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seem to be a bit not clean. You are referring to the same product but yet in some cases you call $product or $_product or $this->getProduct().

For your particular issue, try replacing `$this->getProduct()` with `$product` and give it a try.